# Applying different style to noSelectionOption on PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu

Tags: primefaces

PrimeFaces `p:selectOneMenu` items has a property called `noSelectionOption` which is basicly selected when no option is selected.

I would like my `p:selectOneMenu` to look a bit different when a value is selected or not, but nothing in HTML change on the DOMElement of the `p:selectOneMenu` when the `noSelectionOption` option is selected or not.

Any idea ?

Comment: Isn't that option at a fixed position in the list? You should be able to use a CSS selector to style it.

Comment: Use jquery on the ajax events to find a selected option and style the ancestor html elements

Comment: @JasperdeVries nothing indicate the index of the value select in the DOM element.

Comment: @Kukeltje The problem with adding Javascript is that if PrimeFaces update some components, I do not know how to catch every rerender of the page (without refresh) to set the events.

Comment: Then you have two other possible solutions: 1) push the css spec committee to implement an ancestor selector. 2) override the PF SelectOneMenu renderer to dynamically add a class to the main div if it has a selection.

Comment: any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you've missed, but the CSS class `ui-noselection-option` is applied to the list item (`li`) of the no select option. Tested with:

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="0" noSelectionOption="true"/>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This now leaves you with [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

For example:

```
.ui-noselection-option {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: The way I read it, OP wants to style the the 'container' (e.g, make the input field yellow if nothing is selected yet). That can only be done by parent selectors. But now I think of it, a `style="#{selection.count >0}"` on the `p:selectOneMenu` should also work, but you might be right and I just assumed the question was more complex due to your answer being too obvious

Comment: @Kukeltje ah, I think you are right. In that case I would go with setting a class to the component in case the bound value is empty.

Comment: It was all about setting up a class on the label shown as the actual value (when option list is not shown) not on the option among the list.